# Save 32bits from a 64bit register in x64 env

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, nasm

I'm getting back to my previous topic, but with nothing more than a few thoughts.

I want to store a 32-bit integer in a matrix in assembler in x64. Let's say I have:

```
int** matrix = ...;
matrix[x][y] = 0;
```

Normally I'd simply calculate a position to which I would like to save by doing:

```
mov rax, [rdi + rsi * 8]
mov [rax + rdx * 4], rcx
```

My question is: how can I align rcx to save only 4-bytes? Or maybe I do save 4-bytes only and there is no chance to overwrite some other integer next to the one to overwrite?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ecx` instead of `rcx`.

That's all.

Comment: But rcx is a parameter of the "function" I call to make the assignment. Does it mean ecx stands for the 32 bits of the register?

Comment: OMG, you don't even know that ecx is part of rcx?

Comment: Nop? Quite new to asm and x64. Sorry to say.

Comment: @user767849 yes, ecx is the mnemonic for the 32 lower bits, like cx is for the 16 LSbits, like bl is for the 8 LSbits

Comment: Thanks, dema80. That's how you answer without some weird nerdy rage.

Comment: @user767849 There's an illustration of amd64 registers on this page: http://freecode4freedom.blogspot.de/2009/12/porting-32-bit-appications-to-64-bit-in.html The last picture on the page shows how parts of registers are addressed.

Comment: Thanks. Will see into that!